# Show scroll for child of element with flex-grow 1

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to obtain a simple **layout** composed by a stack of **header**, **main section**, **footer**.

I'm using bootstrap 5.

The entire **layout** must cover all the available space in width and height, overflow (x and y) must be hidden.

**Header** and **wrapper** must take all the needed space.

**Main section** must be in between **header** and **footer** and must take all the available space.
**Main section** is composed by a **sidebar** and an area that will contain the **main content**.

**Sidebar** and **main content** are disposed side by side.
**Sidebar** must take 1/6 of the entire width available.
**Main content** must take the rest of available space in width.

Here is some code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column wrapper">
      <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light header">
          <div class="px-3">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              Header
            </a>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <section class="flex-grow-1 d-flex section">
        <div class="col-2 sidebar">
          <ul class="nav flex-column menu-nav">
            <li class="nav-item px-3 py-2">
              Sidebar
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col p-2 px-3 content">
          Main content
        </div>
      </section>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light header">
        <div class="px-3">
          Footer
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
  <style>
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .header {
      background-color: #1ea185;
    }

    .wrapper {
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .section {
    }

    .sidebar {
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: auto;
      background-color: #fff;
    }

    .content {
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: auto;
      background-color: #eff6f6;
    }
  </style>
</html>
```

I would like to show overflow-y for **sidebar**/**main content** when it's needed. But I would also like to preserve the position of **footer**.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="col p-2 px-3 content relative">
      <div class="absolute inset-0 overflow-y-scroll"> 
          Main content
      </div>
    </div>
```

Set the .content container as relative, then put content in inner div of absolute inset-0.

Edit: this is just an example, I was using tailwind syntax on the class, bootstrap might be slightly different classNames

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="d-flex flex-column wrapper">
      <div>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-light header">
          <div class="px-3">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
              Header
            </a>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <section class="flex-grow-1 d-flex section">
        <div class="col-2 sidebar">
          <ul class="nav flex-column menu-nav">
            <li class="nav-item px-3 py-2">
              Sidebar
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col p-2 px-3 content relative">
          <div class="absolute inset-0 overflow-y-scroll"> 
              Main content
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-light header">
        <div class="px-3">
          Footer
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </body>
  <style>
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .header {
      background-color: #1ea185;
    }

    .wrapper {
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .section {
    }

    .sidebar {
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: auto;
      background-color: #fff;
    }

    .content {
      height: 100%;
      overflow-y: auto;
      background-color: #eff6f6;
    }
  </style>
</html>
```